# Why can't constexpr be used for non-const variables when the function only uses the types?

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr, type-traits

Maybe the title is not clear, so concretely:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
constexpr int test(T)
{
    return std::is_integral<T>::value;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr int a = test(1); // right
    constexpr int b = test(1.0); // right
    int c = 2;
    constexpr int d = test(c); // ERROR!
    return 0;
}
```

In fact, the function doesn't use anything but the type of the parameter, which can be determined obviously in the compilation time. So why is that forbidden and is there any way to make `constexpr` get the value when only the type of parameter is used?

In fact, I hope to let users call the function through parameters directly rather than code like `test<decltype(b)>`, which is a feasible but not-convenient-to-use way, to check if the types of parameters obey some rules.

Comment: The error is very clear `read of non-const variable 'c' is not allowed in a constant expression`. The expression reads non-const variable, thus the expression is not constexpr. `const int c = 2;` is allowed.

Comment: @273K But in fact I even don't read it... I only use the type.

Comment: @o_oTurtle But you do read it, to pass it to the function.  Just because the function doesn't end up using it doesn't mean the expression calling the function doesn't need to follow the normal rules.

Comment: In fact, it reads the value on the stack.

Comment: @273K Okay, so it's impossible to write code to fulfill this requirement, right?

Comment: `const int c = 2;` - making it const is enough

Comment: Change the `test` function to take a template parameter instead of a function parameter.

Comment: @Eljay erm... This is what I mentioned in the last part of the description.

Comment: If you nix all the possible ways to fulfill the requirement, you make it impossible to fulfill the requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take `T` by reference so it doesn't need to read the value:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr int test(T&&)
{
    return std::is_integral<std::remove_cvref_t<T>>::value;
}
```

You can even declare `test` with `consteval`, if you want to.

(Note that stripping cv-qualifiers isn't necessary in this instance; cv-qualified integral types satisfy the `std::is_integral` trait.)

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't constexpr be used for non-const variables when the function only uses the types?

Because the call expression `test(c)` is not a *constant expression* and hence it cannot be used as an initializer for `d`.

Basically, for the call expression `test(c)` to be a constant expression, `c` **must be** a constant expression. It doesn't matter whether `c` is used or not inside the function itself. This is why, the call expressions `test(1)` and `test(1.0)` works and can be used as an initializer for `a` and `b` respectively.

Comment: The other answer says `c` doesn't have to be constexpr if you pass it by reference.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Why are you comparing my answer with the other answer? I am explaining according to what OP has written and asked in their program. In particular, where the argument is passed by value and not by reference. Additionally, there is nothing technically wrong with my answer.

Comment: I've misread the answen then. To me it reads "`c` must be constant [regardless of what `test` is]".

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yeah, I was only talking about OP's code example and just explaining the problem in that as the other answer already answers the second part of the question(which is how to solve it).